# sticked to vs stuck at vs glued to

Tags: meaning, phrases, phrase-usage

I'm not a native English speaker, so to me these three phrases sound ok:

- This system consists of NFC codes *sticked to* the tables.
- This system consists of NFC codes *stuck at* the tables.
- This system consists of NFC codes *glued to* the tables.

I have the impression that not all of them are correct. What is the best way to say this?

I'm also confused with the words at and to. Which one should I use in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'*At*' wouldn't be correct in this context; you'll want to use '*to*.'

'*Sticked*', unless I am mistaken, isn't an actual word - the correct past participle would be '*stuck*.' Both '*stuck*' and '*glued*' would work in your case.